# Sitecore 7.2: Prevent items being deleted by publish

Tags: sitecore, publish

On a Sitecore 7.2 content delivery instance I'm generating items in a folder on the web database, since there is no master db on content delivery. This works well. But the problem is that the generated items would be removed on a publish above its folder.

Is there a way to prevent the folder containing the generated items on web db to be removed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no option.

In fact you should **never** generate content in `web` database directly.

There are multiple options, like generating the data in `master` database and autopublishing to `web` or storing the data in external databases.

More can be read e.g. here: https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/2355/options-for-handling-user-generated-content

Comment: Since content delivery has no master db, I went the way to use another db for user generated content. Thanks as always :)